# Sky Force Reloaded Secret Achievements

Tags: achievements, sky-force-reloaded

By now I have 27 of 30 achievements, you can get most of secret achievements by completing all stages with each different plane.
Does anyone know how to get "Devastator" achievement?
And what is the other secret achievements?

Comment: Can you post what secret achievements have you unlocked?

Comment: I would post an answer if I had the reputation, but you cannot get the “Devastator” achievement. As per PeterID’s comment, “The "Devastator" achievement being revealed on Android is a mistake on our end. It was a strong candidate for the achievements list during the development, but we've decided to cut it out some time ago.” http://forums.toucharcade.com/showthread.php?p=3935647#post3935647

Answer (score 2):

01.) Desert Rose - You've noticed the burning trees by now
     [Get all medals in Level 1 through Hard difficulty]

02.) Nightfall - You rescue all the survivors. Most of the times.
     [Get all medals in Level 2 through Hard difficulty]

03.) Tank You - You're starting to like rockets. Slowly
     [Get all medals in Level 3 through Hard difficulty]

04.) Secret Hideout - You visit the piggy bank often
     [Get all medals in Level 4 through Hard difficulty]

05.) Hitting a Wall - You could do it on foot just as well.
     [Get all medals in Level 5 through Hard difficulty]

06.) Swiss Cheese - Flamethrower is your favorite of enemy towers. For now.
     [Get all medals in Level 6 through Hard difficulty]

07.) Toxic Friendship - Missiles are no longer able to surprise you.
     [Get all medals in Level 7 through Hard difficulty]

08.) Bird of Prey - You're a bit tired of sandstorms. You miss the sea.
     [Get all medals in Level 8 through Hard difficulty]

09.) Burial at Sea - You've reached the sea, but it's not as you remembered it.
     [Get all medals in Level 9 through Hard difficulty]

10.) Overcooked - You're not really curious what is Scarlett cooking in there.
     [Get all medals in Level 10 through Hard difficulty]

11.) Bleeding Heart of Scarlett - You'd trade your car for that tank anytime.
     [Get all medals in Level 11 through Hard difficulty]

12.) Laser What? - Raptors. Laser Raptors.
     [Get all medals in Level 12 through Hard difficulty]

13.) Alpha or Omega - (Omega) will return in next week's episode!
     [Get all medals in Level 13 through Hard difficulty]

14.) My Weekend Job - You've won a tournament. Perhaps.
     [Get the top spot among friends in a tournament]

15.) It's My Birthday! Again... - Ther's a pile of empty boxes in your room.
     [Open 50 Gift Boxes]

16.) Hidden - ???

17.) Beyond the Wall - Those towers were there to protect you.
     [Destroy all towers in Level 5: You must unlock a card to do this]

18.) Test Pilot - You've got them all. Now pick your favorite.
     [Obtain all spaceships]

19.) Full House - Now you can score even more points.
     [Obtain all cards]

20.) Hidden - ???

21.) Don't Fix It - You've come to appreciate this vintage Classic.
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Classic]

22.) Leave No Man Behind - You've made tons of friends in red jumpsuits.
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Ambulance]

23.) Sword Of Bullets - You like to look them in the eyes.
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Gladius]

24.) Out of My Way - If only they'd come in red...
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Enforcer]

25.) Bulletproof - When you're in the mood for a joyride.
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Iron Clad]

26.) Sublight Engines - You can't sit on your... engines for more than a few seconds.
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Swift Justice]

27.) Trigger Happy - The Bro came at you. And regretted it instantly
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Limp Berserker]

28.) Win Some, Lose Some - Lemmy just tell you- Good job!
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Ace of Spades]

29.) Swarm Rockets - There's no place they can hide from you.
     [Beat levels 1 to 13 with the Octopus]

30.) Hidden - ???

Comment: They wanted to know what the hidden ones were, but you left them marked as "hidden"... Furthermore the only achievement OP specifically asked for was Devastator, which **isn't in your list**. I assume it's one of the hidden ones.

Comment: Good to see you've made a list, but you are not using the Markdown syntax. [Here is the Markdown cheatsheet.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/editing-help)